# how to correct find("id = $view")); in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, find

I'm learning cakephp from [here](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/building_a_blog_with_cakephp_part_1_getting_started.html) codes are from the older version of cake so some of the code needs to be updated I have controller which pass data to a view or a layout here is the controller:

BlogController.php

```
<?php
class BlogController extends AppController {

  var $name = 'Blog';
  var $uses = array('Blog');
  // Used when indexing the page (http://yourdomain.com/blog/)
function index($view = null) {
    // What to do if a view is set
    if (isset($view))
    {
      //problem is here
      $this->set('article', $this->Blog->find("id = $view"));
      $this->render('article');
    }
    else
    {
      $this->set('articles', $this->Blog->find('all'));
    }
  }
}
?>
```

the problem is this line `$this->set('article', $this->Blog->find("id = $view"));`

if I replace the line with `$this->set('article', $this->Blog->find('first'))` it will show me the first item always and nothing will go wrong how can I correct this line so that I can use id?

the layout is article.ctp as follow

```
<div id="article">
<h1><?= $article['Blog']['title'] ?></h1>
<p class="date"><?= $article['Blog']['date'] ?></p>
<p class="intro"><?= $article['Blog']['introtext'] ?></p>
<p class="main"><?= $article['Blog']['maintext'] ?></p>
</div>
```

here is the error that I will get by clicking one of items:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: id = 2 [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 2666]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
    $this->set('article', $this->Blog->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Blog.id' => $view))));
```

See: [Retrieving Your Data - CakePHP Manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)